# 'git pull' direct 'fast-forword'mode delete my local file?

Tags: git

I delete the 'readme.md' file on github.

'readme.md' file is still on my local.

Originally I 'git pull' git will remind me auto-conflict failed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrLow.png).

Then I run 'git mergetool',it remind me choose[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oppfu.png).

Later I choose'delete'.A similar situation occurs again.

when I 'git pull' it won't remind me conflict.

It will 'fast-forword' delete my local file directly[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeehX.png).

How should I cancel it 'fast-forword' delete my local file?

Comment: If the remote branch deleted the file, and you have no changes to the files in the branch you're merging into, then there isn't a conflict, the file is just deleted.

Comment: Also, please use the preview function when writing questions on Stack Overflow, you'll get many more eyeballs on your question if you make a slight effort in formatting your question so it is readable.

Comment: yes,you are right.I think I should Add the newline.

Comment: [Why git rm --cached not remove local ever tracked file but others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55663325/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

I know.It's because the delete file on github is the latest submission.So it won't remind me conflict when I pull.